# CloudWatch custom EC2 metrics: missing disk usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

Following the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html) I've setup the following crontab job to reports metrics about memory and disk usage:

```sh
*/5 * * * * ~/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-used-incl-cache-buff --mem-util --mem-used --mem-avail --disk-path=/dev/xvda1 --disk-space-units=megabytes --disk-space-util --disk-space-used --disk-space-avail --from-cron
```

The problem is that in CloudWatch under `AllMetrics -> SystemLinux -> InstanceId` I can see only memory metrics while disk metrics are completely missing:

[image]

What am I missing?
IAM role is correctly configured with the required policies.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using old and no longer maintained metric scripts, instead of [CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html)? Lack of support and being old could explain why they don't work as expected.

Comment: Disk metrics come from EC2 automatically and don't require a script. It might be that the disk was hardly used during the metric period and zeros are not tracked in CloudWatch. Try generating a lot of disk usage and see whether some stats come through.

Comment: @Marcin I will give it a try to CloudWatch Agent, thanks

Comment: @JohnRotenstein disk IOPS metrics come from EC2 automatically, but disk space usage  (how much space is free on the file system) require the CloudWatch Agent to be installed on the EC2 instance.